# Updating One Table Using Another Tables Values

Tags: sql, case

I have imported a sheet from Excel that has values such as:

```
ID NAME MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT SUN
```

Mon-Sun have time values in them.

I want to insert all those values into another table.

The problem comes that comes in is in the other table, MON-TUE-WED-THU, etc all become one column called `DayOfWeek` which has an INT value. So Monday in the first table becomes 2, Tuesday becomes 3 in DayOfWeek and so forth.

Seems easy? Well the values from table 1 will have to be duplicated in the new table that includes DayOfWeek because an ID and NAME have many time values. For example, they can work on TUE, THU.

Will I have to use a CASE statement for this approach?

Example:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (ID, DayOfWeek, StartTime)
SELECT ID, CASE 
WHEN MON IS NOTNULL THEN '1'
END AS DayOfWeek
```

I feel it will be more complex than that.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (Id, [DayOfWeek], StartTime)
SELECT Id, 1, Sun
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT Id, 2, Mon
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT Id, 3, Tue
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT Id, 4, Wed
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT Id, 5, Thu
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT Id, 6, Fri
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT Id, 7, Sat
FROM table1
```

You can add a `Where [Mon] IS NOT NULL` if needed